# Unable to ssh to master node in mesos local cluster installed system

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am a newbie to Mesos. I have installed a DCOS cluster locally in one system (Centos 7).

Everything went up properly and I am able to access the GUI of DCOS  but when I am trying to connect through CLI, it is asking me for password.

I have not been prompted for any kind of password during local installation through vagrant.

But when I issue the following command:

```
[root@blade7 dcos-vagrant]# dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader

Running `ssh -A -t core@192.168.65.90 ssh -A -t core@192.168.65.90 `
core@192.168.65.90's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
core@192.168.65.90's password:
```

I don’t know the password to be given. 
Kindly help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Did you try using your local machine user password?

Comment: Should not you use `centos` as a user name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command shows that you are trying to login to the server using the userid "core". If you do not know the password of user "core", I suggest reset "core" user password and try it again.

Comment: You should be correctly setting the ssh keys as described here: https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/sshcluster/ This way you don't need to use password based authentication.

Comment: Could you please let me know how t reset it? I am not aware . of resetting it in container setup

Comment: @PravinK I am stuck at the same step. How did you generate the .pem file for local cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Since the local installation bases on vagrant, you can use the following convenient workaround: **directly log into the virtual machines by using vagrant's ssh**.

1. open a terminal and enter `vagrant global-status` to see a list of all running vagrant environments (name/id)
2. switch into your dcos installation directory (e.g., `cd ~/dcos-vagrant`), which contains the file `Vagrantfile`
3. run `vagrant ssh <name or (partial) id>` in order to ssh into the virtual machine. For example, `vagrant ssh m1` connects to the master/leader node, which gives you essentially the same shell as `dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader` would do.

Two more tips:

- within the virtual machine, the directory `/vagrant` is mounted to the current directory of the host machine, which is nice for transferring files into/from the VM
- you may try to find out the correct ssh credentials of the default vagrant user and then add these (rather than the pem file retrieved from a cloud service provider) via `ssh-add` to your host machine. This should give you the ability to login via `dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader --user=vagrant` without a password